# Are there any phrases expressing the meaning "won't do/finish something until the last minute of deadline/due time"

Tags: phrase-requests

Some people prefer to finish their tasks one day or even one hour before the deadline. I wonder how native speakers of English say this. Specifically, how to complete the following sentences:

> The class starts at 8 a.m.; please arrive in the classroom at least 10 minutes in advance. Do not _________ [arrive in the classroom exactly at 8].
>
> You always ________ [submit the homework assignment at the last minute of the deadline]! Why don't you submit it earlier?

Comment: Probably the most common expression in U.S. English is the rather pedestrian "wait till the last second [or _minute_ or _instant_]." By the way, you are using _summit_ in a rather odd way in sentence 2, it seems to me. Are you sure that's the verb you want? Oh—it just occurred to me that you probably mean _submit_.

Comment: @SvenYargs Oh, I am sorry~~~I meant "submit". This is my common mistake in campus

Answer (score 2):

Consider **[*to cut it close*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cut_it_close)**:

> (*idiomatic*) To judge or finish something close to its limit.

This expression implies that the action was completed on time but suggests that it easily could have been late.

In your sentences it would read:

> - Class starts at 8 am. Arrive on time. Don't cut it close.
> - You always cut it close with your homework. Why don't you submit it earlier?

Answer (score 2):

They are *taking it down to the wire*.

> **down to the wire**
>   until the last possible moment
>   *The election was so close, it went down to the wire and was decided by a court. We had very little time to get the place decorated for the party, which meant that everyone worked right down to the wire.*
>   [- The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+to+the+wire)

Your statements would read:

- The class starts at 8 a.m.; please arrive in the classroom at least 10 minutes in advance. Do not *take it down to the wire*.
- You always *take it down to the wire*! Why don't you submit it earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Procrastination, especially in the academic or scholastic contexts of your two examples, is often called

- to [cram](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cram) *(vt)*
  postpone studying a subject until the few hour prior to a formal examination.
  refers to the “cramming” of preparations in a small available time.

Variantly, the non-idiomatic **procrastinator**, or **to procrastinate**, could be adequate.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. If you cite something, like a dictionary definition, you must mention the source.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **in the nick of time** comes to mind, but I don't remember it being used with negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

There is the expression ***the eleventh hour*** which [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eleventh-hour) defines as

> the last moment or almost too late:
>
> - We only received the signatures at the eleventh hour.
> - an eleventh-hour decision by the union to call off the strike

So your sentences would look like this:

> The class starts at 8 a.m.; please arrive in the classroom at least 10
> minutes in advance. Do not *come in at the eleventh hour*.

> You always submit the homework assignment at the eleventh hour! Why don't you submit it earlier?

Answer (score 0):

"Fergie time" as in:
"Why do you always leave things til Fergie time?"
Or
"It's Fergie time, if we don't get a move on we're going to miss the bus".

From football referencing the manager Alex Ferguson (aka Fergie) and his Manchester United squad that became synonymous with scoring goals (or getting a result, whether that being a late winner or equaliser) very late on in the game/injury time/stoppage time/time added on at the end of a game. Whether this actually happened more for Man Utd is hotly debated but to me it seemed to be true rnough. Similar to 'last gasp' yet used more often by football fans around other football fans but the reference has become popular enough that I have heard women use it whilst getting ready for a night out. Whether they were familiar with it's origins is anyone's guess but they definitely used it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

There are a variety of slang which may be used where ‘delay’ may be used, i.e. prior to the onset of a task or during its execution — inverse haste, if you will.  Here are two which are almost interchangable.

Use of these phrases may seem quaint, dated, peculiar, or rustic to your audience, however.

- **[dilly-dally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilly-dally#English)**
  **[dally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dally#English)**
  *To delay unnecessarily.*
  The second word is also used for a trifle, or unimportant matter; hence the more precise slang of *dilly-dally*, which is to treat any task as if it were a *dally*.
- **[dawdle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dawdle#Verb)**
  *(intransitive) To spend time idly and unfruitfully, to waste time.*
  A minor aside:  does the entymology of this word concern *daddle* or *doddle*?  You decide.